# Strange Bahavior when using RowEnter Event in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, textbox

I have a datagridview, a list with the same content as the datagridview and a textbox, when I change the row, the content of the textbox changes according to the row that I have selected (they are not linked through databind, but I change the content manually). Up to here everything works fine.

Now, I need that, if I modify the content of the textbox, and I change the row selected in the datagridview, before changing the row selected, check if the content of the textbox has been modified, and if it has, ask if I want to save the changes in the list.

For this task, I thought of using the RowEnter event of the datagridview, comparing the content of the textbox with the content of the list, but I ran into a difficulty, when I put a MessageBox inside the rowenter event, to ask if I want to save or not, no matter if I answered yes or no, the row of the datagridview does not change, and I want it to change the row right after asking, whether or not I saved the textbox change, or if there is another way to check if I change the content of the textbox with respect to the list, after changing the row in the datagridview

I leave part of the code that I am using.

```
private void dgvVisitas_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (numeroFilaVisitaActual == e.RowIndex)
    {
        if (txtNotasVisita.Text != listaVisitasPaciente[e.RowIndex].Notas)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No es igual"); // If this Message is show, the row don't change
        }
    }
    numeroFilaVisitaActual = e.RowIndex;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether it will address your issue but surely you should be handling `RowLeave` rather than `RowEnter`, because it's the row you're leaving that you want to update. That would mean not having to remember what row you were in because the event handler will tell you.

Comment: Also, don't use two nested `if` blocks like that when you can use one and `&&` the two criteria, i.e. `if (numeroFilaVisitaActual == e.RowIndex && txtNotasVisita.Text != listaVisitasPaciente[e.RowIndex].Notas)`.

Comment: Finally, I'm guessing that the code you posted is just a simplification but I'll mention it just in case: you're not actually testing the result of `MessageBox.Show`. Come to think of it, maybe the two nested `if` blocks only seem like they're not required because of a simplification too. If so, no harm done.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.